Will AKS cluster autoscaler terminate my running pods when node scale down happens
We have a scenario where we have a service bus that will hold thousands of messages at a time. Each message will have a link to a pdf file. Our task is to extract the content of each pdf file and to store it as JSON in an azure blob storage container. An average pdf file will be of thousands of pages, and as per our testing, it will take around half an hour to 45 minutes to process a file
We are using AKS to get this job done. The cluster will contain multiple pods and each pod will process the messages in the service bus. We will use a combination of HPA and cluster auto scaler to scale up our solution. We have a timebound SLA with our customers. Therefore, we want to process as many messages as we can parallelly
While reading about the cluster auto scaler, I came to know that if the resource utilization is low on a node, the cluster auto scaler will automatically terminate that node and respawn its pods on a different existing node. Is my understanding correct ? If it is, how can we stop it from terminating a node until the CPU utilization of the pods goes down to a certain threshold lets say 30% ( Our process is CPU intensive so a pod while processing will not slide down below a certain level )
This is absolutely important because if the auto-scaler terminates a pod midway while servicing a pdf file, we will loose all the processing it has done in the meanwhile, and the respawned pod will have to start over again. We don't have a mechanism to manage states in the pod. When processing of a file completes only then we are saving it to blob container.
Is my understanding of auto-scaler's behavior correct? I have based my understanding on from the following resources

https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/configure-scaling-azure-kubernetes-service/3-cluster-autoscaler
This question on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68005597/what-will-happen-when-codes-in-pod-is-running-while-hpa-scale-down
And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64245970/how-to-avoid-the-last-pod-being-killed-on-automatic-node-scale-down-in-aks
